# Computer/Application having trouble and getting slow while accessing Sql server through LAN, Network is fine

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, networking

I have an web project in asp.net in one of my computers which are connected internally through LAN. The database is in Sql Server kept in another computer. The LAN is connected well. There is no connection error in my programming also. But sometimes in this particular system the page is taking long time to be open, sometime it is showing some exceptions(not everytime again and again). What can be the problem? How can it be solved?
The same project is running good in other computers as well.
My network seems ok, as I can acccess the computer hosting SQL server.

Comment: Unfortunately, if all other computers are running the program/site normally, then there must be an issue with that one particular computer, or the network connection to it.

Verify that you have solid communication lines (cables plugged in securely, etc.).  Do the other computers have CAT6 cables and this one has CAT5 etc.  Also, if you do a ping test, what is your latency on that computer versus other systems when pinging the SQL server.  If you do a `ping -t IP_ADDRESS` do they all succeed or do you have dropped packets.

Please add as much info as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You're just having connection problems.

The page waits for the SQL query's answer to return, and it won't load until it gets the answer.

Check your LAN's connection by pinging between the computer with the project and the SQL server.
If this really is the problem, then the exceptions are probably time-outs.